# Check if the input is all numbers html javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make sure that the user inputs all numbers not letters in weight, height and age

```
function calculate(){
        var w= document.getElementById("weight").value;
        var h=document.getElementById("height").value;
        var a=document.getElementById("age").value;

        //if all numbers enter loop
        var height= Number(h);
        if(document.one.gender[0].checked)
        {var ans= 50+ (height/2) ;}
        else
        {var ans=46+ (height/2) ;}

        alert(ans);
        }
       // else alert("enter numbers only");
```

Comment: Have you tried using isNaN()?

Comment: Always welcome! Could you please upvote and accept my answer below? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the following way:

```
if (isNaN(document.getElementById("weight").value)){
// Not number
} else {
// It is number
}
```

Edited code:

```
function calculate(){
    var w= document.getElementById("weight").value;
    var h=document.getElementById("height").value;
    var a=document.getElementById("age").value;

    if (isNaN(w) || isNaN(h) || isNaN(a)) {
      alert("Please ensure that weight, height and age are integers");
      return;
    }

    //Your code if all numbers

}
```

Comment: Always welcome! Could you please upvote and accept my answer? :)